# how go to iphone settings from objective c for ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, shared

The following URL scheme does not work on iOS 7,

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General:"]];`

Answer (score 2):

all url schemes to iOS settings are removed in iOS5.1 and greater versions (so urls like prefs:root=General&path=Network will no longer work)

**It Is possible in ios 8 Now**

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

all url schemes are removed from ios latest version.your code will work on ios 5 but not on other ios i thing.

Answer (score 0):

This URL scheme has been disabled by Apple in SDK 5.1. Its not possible without Jailbreak.

Comment: In iOS 5.1, the prefs: URL scheme has been removed. You can't use it anymore.

If using private APIs is an option, you can try this:

SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.Preferences"), false);
You have to link against the SpringBoardServices framework then.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible now in iOS 8**

Use the following for iOS 8:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
     NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No, this is not possible in iOS 7.

As other pointed out, the URLScheme was removed in iOS 5, and another approach were added in iOS 8.

Also discussed here:
[Open Settings app from another app programmatically in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840089/open-settings-app-from-another-app-programmatically-in-iphone)