# How can I prompt the user to turn on location services i.e Go to Settings → Privacy → Location Services

Tags: ios, settings, cllocationmanager

Following code doesnt works any more so what could we do

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

Following works for **Go to Settings → Your Application → Location**  but I want to access  **Go to Settings → Privacy → Location Services**

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

I got the trouble same as below questions

[Open Settings app from another app programmatically in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840089/open-settings-app-from-another-app-programmatically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

i use this code if user don't turn on location services

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     if ([[error domain] isEqualToString: kCLErrorDomain] && [error code] == kCLErrorDenied) {
       // The user denied your app access to location information.

       UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location" message:@"You can enable access in Settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
       alert.delegate = self;
       [alert show];
     }


    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}
```

and hanle `Settings` button in `UIAlertView` in this code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%d",buttonIndex);

   if (buttonIndex == 1) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
   }
}
```

Comment: It only works for user to turn on location services after user has denied their use

Comment: in this case , after calling `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` app automatic show my alert with capability to open privacy settings

Comment: if user click cancel by mistake then